# Select last low value from a table

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like this:

```
id | value | datestamp
-----------------------
1  | 89    | 2015-05-25 16:49:25
2  | 60    | 2015-05-26 16:49:25
3  | 42    | 2015-05-27 16:49:25
4  | 12    | 2015-05-28 16:49:25
5  | 3     | 2015-05-29 16:49:25
6  | 95    | 2015-05-30 16:49:25
7  | 75    | 2015-06-01 16:49:25
8  | 52    | 2015-06-02 16:49:25
9  | 31    | 2015-06-03 16:49:25
10 | 12    | 2015-06-04 16:49:25
11 | 99    | 2015-06-05 16:49:25
...
```

The values are percentages, between 100 and 0, always decreasing except one time per cycle, but almost never exactly 0 or 100, just approximately.
Is there an easy select query to get the row with the latest low value? In this case the 10 ID.
Thank you in advance for your help.

**UPDATE**

As Tim Biegeleisen said, it's a gaps and islands problem.  I want the last row in the table where the value coming both before and after are larger, except in the case of the last row.

Comment: how do you say the row with ID 10 has the latest low value?

Comment: I mean there are minimums in the values fields, in this example: 3 and 12 each one with a date, and i need the latest minimum, in this case the 12

Comment: One way I see is minimum value within a month because 3 is in a different month and 12 is in a different month. If that is the case they try the query I have posted in the answer.

Comment: I gave an answer, but then deleted it, because I think this is really a gaps and islands problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are right, i did't know the "gaps and islands" term before, but right, I want the last value in the table where the value coming both before and after are larger, except in the case of the last row

Comment: I don't have time for a solution now, but I will check back and if no one else has answered, I will try to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is a simple task for a human, this is hard to express in SQL

> The values are percentages, between 100 and 0, always decreasing except one time per cycle

I solved this with a self join which should deliver the best performance. However, you should create (if not already done) an index on datestamp.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tbl1 a
INNER JOIN tbl1 b ON b.datestamp > a.datestamp
WHERE b.value > a.value
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.datestamp DESC, b.datestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**UPDATE**

> I want the last row in the table where the value coming both before and after are larger

If you want to be sure you can do this

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tbl1 a
INNER JOIN tbl1 b ON b.datestamp > a.datestamp
INNER JOIN tbl1 c ON c.datestamp < a.datestamp
WHERE b.value > a.value
AND c.value > a.value
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.datestamp DESC, b.datestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

but I don't think that is necesarry.

Answer (score 0):

To get latest value apply sorting on date and then by value

```
Select top(1) * from table order by datestamp desc, value
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

select id,name from table order by  id desc limit 1

Comment: It is just give me the last row, but i need that row which has the latest minimum in values fields, ordered by date

Comment: what result do you want at your sample from above? maybe i can provide

Comment: With the given table example, I want the row with ID=10 because the value=12 is the last minimum.

Comment: How its come up to that result.. this is too generic "last low value". its last but low

Comment: is it depend on date? any bases?

Comment: Its a printer toner level daily statistic, and I want the last date when the toner was changed (the value fields value changed to 99 from 12 as the example above)

Comment: you mean you want the minimum value of toner? so it means min value is set whatever you want.. i guess

Comment: I want that row, when the toner had the last minimum value.

Comment: what would be your default last minimun value? all of that row could be a part of minimum value am i ryt? i think you have to set what value you want as your minimum,, and you are the only one who knew it.

Comment: She wants the most recent local minimum, being defined as a value where the value coming both before _and_ after are larger, except in the case of the last row, where only the previous value has to be larger.

Comment: it means not a last row, it may be second to the last row? in a very low level?

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    id
    , value
    , datestemp 
FROM yourtable yt1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        MIN(yt2.value) minval
        , MONTH(yt2.datestamp) datemonth 
    FROM yourtable yt2
    GROUP BY MONTH(yt2.datestamp)
) yt3 ON yt3.minval = yt1.value AND yt3.datemonth = MONTH(yt1.datestamp)
ORDER BY yt1.datestamp DESC
```

Don't know if My Sql supports TOP clause. In case there is one minimum value in a month then you won't need top clause. The query is based on considering the fact that the minimum you are picking is for latest month.

#### Update:

I think what you want is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY datestamp DESC LIMIT 2
) S 
ORDER BY value LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think this is a gaps and islands problem.

Comment: I really don't know about gaps and islands problem. After reading your comment hit google. It will take me time read and understand the whole stuff. Thanks for introducing this to me.

Comment: The "islands" in the question are the values which are surrounded by values both before and after which are _larger_ (except for possibly the last row).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think you are on the right way, its gaps and islands

Comment: I was just reading and it said this requires row by row processing than set based processing. Would it mean Henrietta would need to process the records row by row and determine the row he wants to pick?

Answer (score 0):

you may be try this

```
select * form tbl_name order by id desc limit 1
```